# YouTube Reporting API .Net Client Library CreateTime Milliseconds

Tags: youtube-api, google-api-dotnet-client

When returning a list of reports that have been generated for a specific job, the API returns a createTime property.  This property value is then used to limit future requests to only include reports createdAfter the max createTime already collected.

The problem is that the client library is not returning millsecond precision.  Instead, I'm getting a string that includes only seconds such as "4/3/2017 11:25:25 AM".

When I use the API explorer, I do get milliseconds in the response json.

Question is, can the client library return milliseconds?  If so, how do I get this values?

The Report property that I'm referring to is called "CreateTime".

```
var reportList = ytReportingService.Jobs.Reports.List(JobId);
reportList.CreatedAfter = "1900-01-01T12:00:00.000000Z";

foreach (Report report in reportListResponse.Reports)
{
//Some irrelevant code is removed
Console.WriteLine("================== Job Report ==================");
Console.WriteLine("Event: " + Event);
Console.WriteLine("ID: " + report.Id);
Console.WriteLine("DownloadUrl: " + report.DownloadUrl);
Console.WriteLine("CreateTime: " + report.CreateTime.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("StartTime: " + report.StartTime);
Console.WriteLine("EndTime: " + report.EndTime);
Console.WriteLine("JobID: " + report.JobId);
Console.WriteLine("JobExpireTime: " + report.JobExpireTime);
}
```

[image]

Update 20170406

CreateTime is returned from the client library as a generic object.  Surprisingly, it allows both get and set.

[image]

Below I'm casting to a datetime data then back to a string and formatting explicitly.

```
((DateTime)job.CreateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"))
```

The result is the same.  No fractional seconds are returned.

[image]

((DateTime)job.CreateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"))

Update 20170406

Correction - The above example is using the Job object's CreateTime property.  While the job does not return fractional seconds, the report.CreateTime does return fractional seconds!

It turns out that report.CreateTime (object) when cast to string directly it does not include the fractional seconds.  The solution is to cast it to a datatime datatype first.  Then, the data can be formatted as needed.

```
((DateTime)report.CreateTime).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff")
```

Comment: Contrary to what you're saying, [Youtube Reports properties](https://developers.google.com/youtube/reporting/v1/reference/rest/v1/jobs.reports#properties) says createTime uses a timestamp in RFC3339 UTC "Zulu" format, accurate to microseconds (Example: "2015-10-02T15:01:23.045678Z".). It would be good if you could give us a raw response

Comment: I agree.  The spec says that I should be getting milliseconds.  I also verified that I do get milliseconds when using the API explorer.  The problem is that the .Net client library is not returning milliseconds.  The code is very simple.  I added an example to the original post.

Comment: Are you certain the problem is in the data rather than how you're converting it to a string? Try `Console.WriteLine("EndTime: " + report.EndTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"))` for example. (Will look into this when I can though.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is the data being returned.  The createtime property is returned as a generic object.  To format it I need to cast it to a datetime. I added notes to the original post to demonstrate the results of formatting the datetime to include fractions of seconds.

Comment: See my latest notes, Jon.  You are correct.  The report.CreateTime is returning fractional seconds!  Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction.  If you want to post an answer, I would be happy to mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jon Skeet posted a comment that let to the answer.  See the final example in the above post.